# htaccess detect and rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I am having a big time issue in using htaccess but got a little more familiar with the help of this forum. but there is one issue where I cant seem to solve with the search function of this forum or perhaps my key words are an issue of its own. here goes the scenario where I hope you guys would enlighten me on:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^u=([0-9])$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])/([^/]*)$ /example/index.php?u=$1&m=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

the above modrewrite is suppose to help me to detect if the parameter for "u" exist and its in numerical form, it will rewrite to the above rules. If else it would use the below rewrite rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^!u=([0-9])$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /example/index.php?m=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Well, as you can see, its not working very well. I really do appreciate any help given here. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution to my own question. Ironic as that is. Here you go:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ example/index.php?u=$1 [QSA,NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ example/index.php?m=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

It's for those who wants to know. =)